Does permutation (row exchange) change the invertibility of a matrix? (a question on Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra book)
On page 114 of Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra (5th), it writes that

If $A$ is invertible, a permutation $P$ will put its rows in the right
order to factor $PA=LU$. There must be a full set of pivots after row
exchanges for $A$ to be invertible.

However, to the best of my knowledge, permutation does not affect the invertibility of a matrix.
Then how should we understand the quoted paragraph?

I would interpret it literally. If invertible then row exchanges will allow $LU$-decomposition. The full set of pivots is equivalent to invertibility.

Think about trying to $LU$-decompose $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. You need the $P$.

@TedShifrin I know... but P doesn't change the invertibility, does it? My question is why Gilbert Strang in the book emphasizes "There must be a full set of pivots after row exchanges for A
to be invertible."

@CyclotomicField Thank you! But what does "The full set of pivots is equivalent to invertibility." mean?

@AStudent it means that all the pivots are non-zero in row reduced form. So once you have it in upper  triangular form the pivots will be the diagonal entries.

No, $P$ does not affect invertibility. But his point here is that not every invertible matrix can be put in $LU$ form. He is elaborating that by using $P$ you can put the pivots (e.g., in the example I gave you) along the diagonal, where you need them to determine invertibility in echelon form. Sometimes, to be honest, Strang's conversational tone in his books can be confusing.

@CyclotomicField Thank you! I got it!

@TedShifrin Thank you! I got it!
